# Eliminate scanned image border (Corona) in ArcMap

Tags: raster, arcmap

I am trying to do an analysis using historical Corona images. The images are scanned, so there is a black boarder around the actual image. When I click on the border with the identify tool, the pixel values are either 1. NoData 2. Pixel values between 0-7.

I would like to create a seemless mosaic using 5 Corona images. To do this, it seems to me that I need to remove the border surrounding the actual image. How can I do this?

If this method can be made easily iterable, that would be even better.[image: see attached image with borders]

I have already added an attribute table for all of the rasters. This attribute table contains only objectID, value, and count.

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to create a polygons covering the image area for each raster then use the [Clip tool](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/clip.htm) (or the [Extract by Polygon tool](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/extract-by-polygon.htm) if you have a Spatial Analyst license) to set the border as NoData. then you just have to check in the symbology tab of the raster properties that the NoData values are set to no color